# DRY url with backbone router and django urls?

Tags: django, backbone.js

In django, `{% url 'url_name' %}` or `{{ obj_instance.get_absolute_url }}` is used for urls and actual url is defined in urls.py

I'm recently starting to use backbone router and it has the form of

```
routes: {
 '..some/url/path/:param_name/': 'func_name'
}
```

Is it possible to use django's url-related function in backbone router so we can keep the dry-ness of urls?

**edit**

I'm using `the/whole/relative/path/from/root` in backbone routes.
Is this a bad practice in backbone? (This is my first time using a router.)

The need for the absolute path arises because I want to router in multiple apps as described in the following.

I have 3 apps that show the followings.

1. list of all musics (/forum)
2. list of all musics in an album (/album/:album_id)
3. detail of music (/album/:album_id/music/:music_id)

If a user lands in #1, by clicking a music, he can go to #3. 
From #3, he can go to #2 or #1.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding, in Django you define the url which goes inmediatly after the domain. And in backbone router you define the url which goes after the "#" tag. So for example, if you enter two different domains without any argument and you call to the same backbone router, they both will be catched as empty url.

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "defaultFunc"  //nothing after # (it doesn't care about the url before that)
        "posts/:id": "getPost" // #posts/12
    }
});
```

In conclussion, I think that each one has to do the their work. Django for server side url with their arguments, and backbone for the client side.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I'm using "the/whole/absolute/path" as backbone routes, is this a bad practice? I've updated the question.

Comment: And does it work?
Depending on how do you want to distribute the work between Django an Backbone.
If you put: /album/mydisc/#song/mySong -> The template of /album/mydisc will load Django template engine, and then Backbone will do the work for the song. If you want to delegate everything to backbone, you should put: #album/mydisc/song/mySong

Comment: I have it working except one case 'go to #1 #3' and 'back-button to #1' doesn't show #1 page. I have all three urls in server urls as well.